# .htaccess 301 redirects wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying top redirect a standard Wordpress "folder" URL of a page to a new one on the same domain while keeping all subfolders, query strings etc. From `domain/old-path/` to `domain/new-path/`.

Now I have this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/old-path(.*) /new-path$1
```

It works, but `domain/old-path` redirects to `domain/new-path` and, this being WP, another redirect happens from `domain/new-path` to `domain/new-path/`.

I would like both `domain/old-path` and `domain/old-path/` to redirect straight to `domain/new-path/` with the ending `/`.
All this while, like I said, keeping all "subfolders", query strings etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...this being WP, another redirect happens from `example.com/new-path` to `example.com/new-path/`.

If `/new-path` is a physical directory then it's not WP that is triggering the redirect, it is Apache's mod_dir that is "fixing" the URL.

However, since you are using WordPress, it is preferable to use mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule`) to perform the redirect instead of a mod_alias `RedirectMatch` in order to avoid conflicts. Different modules execute at different times during the request and WP already uses mod_rewrite.

Try something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file *before* any existing WP directives:

```
RewriteRule ^dir/?(.*) /new-dir/$1 [R,L]
```

As you can see, although the slash is optional in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, this is never captured by the regex and the slash is always present in the *substitution*.

Change the `R` (temporary) redirect to a `R=301` only when you are sure it's working OK.

Comment: Thank you, that works! Am i to understand that `/?` means "with or without the `/` "?

Comment: Also, why does `RewriteRule ^dir/?(.*) /new-dir/$1 [R,L]` work, but `RewriteRule ^/dir/?(.*) /new-dir/$1 [R,L]` doesn't?

Comment: Yes, the `?` is a regex meta character that makes the preceding character/group optional. `^/dir/?(.*)` will never match in a directory/.htaccess context because the URL-path that the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ matches against never starts with a slash. The directory-prefix (of where the `.htaccess` file is located) is first removed from the request URI (this notably ends in a slash, so the slash is always removed before matching). This is different to when these directives are used directly in the server config (or virtual host).

Comment: So the patter has to be relative to the location of `.htaccess` when using `mod_rewrite` and without the slash, but the destination must be from the root of the domain and including a slash, correct? Damn, this is alot to wrap my head around, but I think you've set me in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, the pattern is relative to the location of `.htaccess`. The destination (or _substitution_) doesn't need to be root-relative - but it does for external redirects (as in the above)! OK, that may not help the confusion. Try removing the slash prefix on the _substitution_ (it will break)... If you specify a relative path (no slash prefix) then the directory-prefix that was removed earlier is prefixed to the substitution. The directory-prefix is a filesystem path (not a URL) so this will break horribly in the above example.

Comment: However, you might use a relative _substitution_ if you are doing some URL-rewriting. In which case this is an _internal rewrite_, as opposed to an _external redirect_ (that you are doing here). You can internally rewrite to a filesystem path (as opposed to a public URL), so a relative substitution might be appropriate in this situation.

Comment: It actually works with or without the `/`. To simplify, the _substitution_ with a slash is root domain relative while without it's `.htaccess` directory relative? I ask because `RewriteRule dir/?(.*) new-dir/$1 [R=301,L]` redirects from `domain/htaccess-dir/foo/bar/dir` to `domain/htaccess-dir/new-dir/` while `RewriteRule dir/?(.*) /new-dir/$1 [R=301,L]` redirects from `domain/htaccess-dir/foo/bar/dir` to `domain/new-dir/`.

Comment: "It actually works with or without the `/`" - In that case you have a `RewriteBase` directive that defines the _base_ URL for all _relative_ substitutions. (Sorry, I just overlooked the fact you are using WP - that usually sets the `RewriteBase`.) "To simplify, the _substitution_ with a slash is root domain relative << **yes** / while without it's `.htaccess` directory relative << **yes, except if you have set `RewriteBase`**". For your example to work, you must have a `RewriteBase` directive set (or you are seeing a cached redirect).

Comment: Correct! I thnink I get it now. Interestingly, while the `RewriteRule`s seem to be executed in order, the `RewriteBase` seems to affect all of them, including ones that come before. Also `RewriteBase` makes slash-less _substitutions_ work with URIs instead of file system directories, correct? But why does a slash-less `RewriteBase` result in a 500?

Comment: Yes... RewriteBase can only really occur once in the htaccess file. If it occurs more than once then the last instance wins and controls the entire htaccess file. (The same as with the RewriteEngine directive.)

Comment: Thank you for your time, kind sir!